# iOS - Read information from website input

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to build an iOS app for my school and one section of the app is "Food of the week" which basically should display what is for lunch in the school.
Something like:
Monday: 
Tuesday:
And so on..

The people that decide what's for lunch should be able to change this every week, through a website I think is the easiest way.

Should I be using RSS? Any suggestions what is a good way for doing this?
[I found this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) but I'm not sure this is the thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for implementing it in an iOS app would be using a JSON web service.
Vary basically, you'd have a page on your server, that would display a JSON representation of the weekley menu :

```
{
     "Monday" : [
         "First option",
         "Second option",
         "Third option",
     ],
     "Tuesday" : [
         "First option",
         "Second option",
     ],
     ...
}
```

Then, get this data using a classic iOS network query (or using a library like AFNetworking if you want).

After, parse if using `+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error` from `NSJSONSerialization`.

From how I've defined the JSON representation, you would get your informations like that (assuming that `dic` is the NSDictionary resulted from `JSONObjectWithData` :

```
// Get day
NSArray * day = dic[@"Monday"];
NSString * firstOption = dic[0];
// You could also use loops on your dictionaries / arrays.
```

**To do so, you might really want to understand what JSON is, and how it works (generally and in iOS**.

Good luck !

Comment: Your welcome. Please flag as answer if it is what you asked for ;-).